# Changing SymbolLayer properties on click when using a VectorSource

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I've been following this guide provided by Mapbox to familiarize myself with SymbolLayers and how to manipulate their properties on the map.

https://blog.mapbox.com/a-guide-to-the-android-symbollayer-api-5daac7b66f2c

The key step I'm having issues with is Step 5 where they update the `iconSize` property onMapClick. After they add a property to the selected `Feature`, the guide says to call `source.setGeoJson(featureCollection);` in order to reset the source of the layer.

The project I'm working with uses a `VectorSource` as the source of data for the `SampleLayer`, not a `GeoJsonSource` like the example uses. The problem is that `VectorSource` doesn't provide a method like `setGeoJson` so I'm not able to reset the layer source after I change the property.

What can I do to work around this without having to change all of our source data?

```java
for (Feature feature : featureCollection.getFeatures() {
  if (feature.getStringProperty("title").equals(selectedFeature.getStringProperty("title"))) {
    feature.getProperties().addProperty("selected", true);  
  }
}

source.setGeoJson(featureCollection);
```

The full source of that example can be found here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/286f33d848c9fea48de908b144682081961b986b/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/labs/SymbolLayerMapillaryActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this issue in the future, the only possible approach here would be to remove and add layer again, with the updated source. This is however an ineffective solution, so it would really be better for you to use GeoJson source instead.